# Find the mean cost of maintenance in the first year of purchase of the machine.

Tags: probability-distributions

> A sewing machine within first year of its purchase requires $X$ number of inspection visit by a maintenance technician and $X$ follows a poisson distribution with $\mu=4$
>
> (i) First visit is free of charge and subsequent visit costs $1000$ each. Find the mean cost of maintenance in the first year of purchase of the machine.

$\underline{Attempt}$

- Since mean number of inspection visit maintenance technician within first year is 4 and first visit is free of charge,
  Mean cost of maintenance in the first year of purchase of the machine $3 \times 1000=3000$

Can anyone verify my answer?

Comment: This may seem intuitively correct, but it's not. The answer given below by @Haagexa is correct, although the explanation is somewhat obscure.

Comment: @DavidQuinn Can you show your answer with details?

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Y$ is the number of payments of 1000 made each year, then the expected value of $Y$ is given by

$$E(Y)=0(p(X=0\cup1)+1p(X=2)+2p(X=3)+3p(X=4)+...$$
$$=\sum_{r=2}^\infty(r-1)e^{-\mu}\frac{\mu^r}{r!}$$
$$=e^{-\mu}\left[\sum_{r=2}^\infty\frac{\mu^r}{(r-1)!}-\sum_{r=2}^\infty\frac{\mu^r}{r!}\right]$$
$$=e^{-\mu}\left[\mu\sum_{r=2}^\infty\frac{\mu^{r-1}}{(r-1)!}-(e^{\mu}-\mu-1)\right]$$
$$=e^{-\mu}\left[\mu\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{\mu^{j}}{j!}-e^{\mu}+\mu+1\right]$$
$$=e^{-\mu}\left[\mu(e^\mu-1)-e^{\mu}+\mu+1\right]$$
$$=\mu-1+e^{-\mu}$$

And hence the result...

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Poisson distributions have positive probability of taking the value $0$, therefore the expected expense in the first year is $$E[1000\max\{0,X-1\}]=1000E[X-1+\textbf{1}_{\{0\}}(X)]=\\=1000(E[X]-1+P(X=0))=1000(\mu-1+e^{-\mu})$$ instead of $1000(\mu-1)$.

Comment: Can you explain your answer further?

Comment: @puka If you have three apples, two oranges and a Poisson distribution with mean $\mu$, then...